# Parse Sequence to Create Batch NDShape

Tags: c#

I am using CNTK 2.7, and I am trying to create a batch of Inputs:

```
Value.Create<double>(NDShape.CreateNDShape(new[] { 5 }), Ins, new[] { false }, DeviceDescriptor.CPUDevice, true);
```

My Input Array:

```
Output: Matrix: 5 x 6
<0, -0.706874154584897, -0.768999702839999, 0.937874451744898, 0.937874451744898, 0.478825290511127, >
<0, 0.704566469852247, -0.891316078025938, 0.97077039154423, -0.595882547878185, -0.811861764507646, >
<0, 0.768999702839999, 0.706874154584897, 0.540950838766229, 0.937874451744898, 0.875748903489796, >
<0, -0.741060607623135, -0.913317696495672, 0.976687538087921, 0.827742911127463, -0.445074381990199, >
<0, 0.906342830401675, 0.88115453808841, -0.375234162798297, 0.974811707686736, 0.949623415373472, >
```

The Error:

```
About to throw exception 'Value::Create: The number of elements (6) in the vector containing sequence data must be a multiple of the size (5) of specified sample shape '[5]''
```

I am not sure this is an understandable error message for the average Human, not until one knows why its throwing this error.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it, dumb as it is:

Each Input Vector is:

```
<0, -0.706874154584897, -0.768999702839999, 0.937874451744898, 0.937874451744898, 0.478825290511127, >
```

So a 1x6 Vector of a 5x6 Matrix.

We must have a:

```
NDShape.CreateNDShape(new[] { 1, 6 })
```

or:

```
NDShape.CreateNDShape(new[] { 2, 3 })
```

or

```
NDShape.CreateNDShape(new[] { 3, 2 })
```

To equal 6.

The Input IEnumerable sequenceStartFlags, the 3rd parameter to parse must be like so:

new[] { true, false, false, false, false }

How silly!

[image]

Dumb coding results in dumb errors!

Honestly, a little smarter approach here would be to infer the dimensions and ask for a batch size of the vector!

If you get these sequences right, you will be fine ;*)

Some Notes: Implementing a batchSize

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Factorisation:
// NDShape.CreateNDShape(new int[] { 1, 6 }) is the Shape of the Input Vector andnot the Matrix!
// This means, if the Vector of Matrix[0] = 6, we are inputting One Batch!
// CreateX breaks the Matrix down into Vectors, and then into Batches of the Vector Size.
// If batchSize = 1, then we need { 1, row } where row = 6.
// If batchSize != 1, then we need a Factor row / batchSize = x but x must be a whole number!
// This means any combination of: { 1, 6 }, { 2, 3 }, { 3, 2 } and any more you can find.
for (factor = 1; factor <= row.Length; factor++)
{
    if (row.Length % factor == 0)
    {
        // We have found a possibility factor that needs to equal the batchSize to use.
        // There could be multiple factors!
        // Else batchSize is incorrect and we need to throw and error.
    }
}
```

EDIT: CreateBatchOfSequences just calls: Create so dopey to use both in one class?

DUUUP: 'Currently, only sequence starting with SequenceBegin is supported.

One must use: Value.CreateBatchOfSequences which sets a 'startFlag' Flag.

```
Value.CreateBatchOfSequences<double>(NDShape.CreateNDShape(new int[] { 1, 6 } ), Ins, DeviceDescriptor.CPUDevice);
```